How to download artifacts from another project pipeline in azure devops
trigger:
  - main

pool: 
  
  name: Default

steps:
- task: DownloadPipelineArtifact@2
  inputs:
    artifactName: "test_artifact"
    project: "Artifact_Demo"  # Specify the name of the project where the artifact is located
    pipeline: "source-pipeline"  # Specify the ID of the pipeline producing the artifact
    buildVersionToDownload: "latest"
    downloadType: "single"
    path: "$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)"
    targetPath: "$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)/test_artifact"

- powershell: |
    Get-ChildItem -Path "$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)\test_artifact" -Recurse
  displayName: 'List Contents of Downloaded Artifact'

Error:

Pipeline Run:


Thanks
I have tried changing the code to
steps:

task: DownloadPipelineArtifact@2
inputs:
buildType: 'specific'
project: 'Artifact_Demo'
definition: 'source-pipeline'
buildVersionToDownload: 'latest'
artifactName: 'test_artifact'
targetPath: '$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)/test_artifact'

getting the error ##[error]Get project failed for project: Artifact_Demo

the error is caused by the project setting  Limit job authorization scope to current project for non-release pipelines is on, please turned it off, so that the pipeline can get the artifact from another project. I added the details below, thanks. :)

What are the additional settings I have to do so that the resources can access the pipeline from another project. Currently the resources feature is not able to trigger the pipeline although the pipeline referenced in the project is successful

For the pipeline resource trigger, you could need to check the Default branch for manual and scheduled builds value, please find the details in doc Branch considerations, and i notice it's already answered in your another ticket. For current ticket, may i know if  my reply below answers? Let me know if you have any queries, glad to help.

The error is caused by the incorrect argument for DownloadPipelineArtifact@2 task.
To fix the error, choose the artifact from another pipeline, please click the grey Settings link above the task -> on the right side, simply manually choose the parameter value -> Click Add button at bottom to override the task content.

The task could be like this(please follow above steps to fix the task content):
- task: DownloadPipelineArtifact@2 
  inputs:
    buildType: 'specific'
    project: 'Artifact_Demo'
    definition: 'source-pipeline'
    buildVersionToDownload: 'latest'
    artifactName: 'test_artifact'
    targetPath: '$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)/test_artifact'

In addition, since the artifact comes from another project, please go to Project settings -> Pipelines -> Settings -> Toggle off the option Limit job authorization scope to current project for non-release pipelines

The pipeline will get the target artifact:

